# ImportXML function in Google Dynamic XML path

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the headlines and landing page URL's from `"New + Updated"` section of this page:
https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/

The issue is that the class `"_988f698c"` keeps changing as the headline is being replaced with a new *headline/topic*.

I need a workaround to use *IMPORTXML* function which will dynamically capture the class of that object in that position. The current formula is:

```
=IMPORTXML(https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/,"//*[@class='_988f698c']")
```

Here is the html tag for example. The class `"_988f698c"` refreshes every hour or so with new headlines coming in.

```
<li class="e9a6bea7">
    <a class="_988f698c" href="https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/reviews/gir-spatula-review/">Why We Love GIR Spatulas</a> 
    <p class="_9d1f22a9">today
    </p>
</li>
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come back a little and look for an alternative path without forcing the use of random numbers.

For the title, use:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/",
           "//ul[@data-testid='new-and-updated']/li/a"
          )
```

For the URL attached to the title:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/",
           "//ul[@data-testid='new-and-updated']/li/a/@href"
          )
```

For the text indicating the day of publication:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/",
           "//ul[@data-testid='new-and-updated']/li/p"
          )
```

---

If you want to collect everything together, use `|` to split the paths:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/",
           "//ul[@data-testid='new-and-updated']/li/a | 
            //ul[@data-testid='new-and-updated']/li/a/@href | 
            //ul[@data-testid='new-and-updated']/li/p"
          )
```

*only use it if you are absolutely sure that the values will always exist, because if they don't, you will have problems with the position in the sheet rows if you define formulas that depend on fixed values in each of the cells.*

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. I might need time to understand the logic, but I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @romi the logic is → instead of using ```[@class='...']``` with random numbers, I went up a few steps and found a fixed attribute called ```@data-testid='new-and-updated'```, being it fixed it gave freedom to go any way I wanted below him.